# AngularJS manage history

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is way to filter window history? When I move from one page to another, then in the history there are similar states like this

`[http://localhost:8080/#/reports/historical?userId=62&tradingDeskId=1&bookingId=1&multiple=false#%253A%255B%25221%2522%255D%252C%2522....`]

Difference only is part after last hashtag, which present serialized JSON object. And when I press on back browser button, I need to click multiple times(4-5) to get to the previous page, because in history

```
- url#hash1 
 - url#hash2 
 - url#hash3 
 - url#hash4
 - url1#hash
 - url2#hash
```

but URL is same

How I can make history to

```
- url#hash
 - url1#hash
 - url2#hash
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this be useful for you to solve your issue:

https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home

Please try.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot use one more dependency and... I think what not clearly described that issue.

Here is example of url:

http://localhost:8080/#/products/statistics?arg1=62&arg2=1&arg3=3&arg4=6183#[very-log-hash]

When I'm moving from **page1** to **page2(above url)**, then in the window history are about four records with the same url, but differently **very-log-hash** like below:

```
.../#/products/statistics?arg1=62&arg2=1&arg3=3&arg4=6183#hash1...
.../#/products/statistics?arg1=62&arg2=1&arg3=3&arg4=6183#hash2...
.../#/products/statistics?arg1=62&arg2=1&arg3=3&arg4=6183#hash3...
.../#/products/statistics?arg1=62&arg2=1&arg3=3&arg4=6183#hash4...
```

To set this **hash** used *$location.hash(params)*

When I press browser back button - nothing happens, because url stay same, only hash is changed, e.g. from **...hash4** I've moved to **...hash3** and so on.

How I can fix this situation? I've tried clean history in the listener but without success.